# Getting 'Unable to translate collection subquery' in the mapper when doing Join in the EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to join several results of LINQ queries in the EF Core

```cs
var frameworkOrg = context.Applications
    .Where(c => c.Certifications.Select(f => f.Framework).Any(fr => fr.Name == search.Framework))
    .Select(apporg => apporg.Organization)
    .Select(t => t);

var coveredDataOrg = context.Applications
    .Where(c => c.PrivacyPolicies.Any(pp => pp.Type == search.DataCovered))
    .Select(apporg => apporg.Organization)
    .Select(t => t);
    
var orgResult = frameworkOrg.Union(coveredDataOrg);
var organizationModel = mapper.ProjectTo<Models.Organization>(orgResult).ToList();
```

But when I am trying to map the results, I get an error below.

> Unable to translate collection subquery in projection since the parent
> query doesn't project key columns of all of it's tables which are
> required to generate results on client side. This can happen when
> trying to correlate on keyless entity or when using 'Distinct' or
> 'GroupBy' operations without projecting all of the key columns.

If I don't use the join, however, and place frameworkOrg or coveredDataOrg into a mapper, there is no error

How can I fix my join statement to avoid the error in the mapper?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine results in one `Where`. `Union` has limitations in translation, especially for navigation properties:

```cs
var orgResult = context.Applications
    .Where(c => c.Certifications.Select(f => f.Framework).Any(fr => fr.Name == search.Framework) 
      || c.PrivacyPolicies.Any(pp => pp.Type == search.DataCovered)
    )
    .Select(apporg => apporg.Organization);

var organizationModel = mapper.ProjectTo<Models.Organization>(orgResult).ToList();
```

If you need to build predicate with `OR` dynamically you can use [Predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)